# How to set different IP according to different commands of one single scrapy.Spider?

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a bunch of pages to scrape, about 200 000.
I usually use Tor and Polipo proxy to hide my spiders behaviors even if they are polite, we never know. So if I login this is useless to use one account and change IP. So that is why I can create several accounts on the website and to set my spider with arguments like in the following:

```
class ASpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.a_website.com/compte/login']

    def __init__ (self, username=None, password=None):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def parse(self, response):
       token = response.css('[name="_csrf_token"]::attr(value)').get()
       data_log = {
                '_csrf_token': token,
                '_username': self.username,
                '_password': self.password
                 }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=data_log, callback=self.after_login) #No matter the rest
```

And to run several same spiders like:

`scrapy crawl spider -a username=Bidule -a password=TMTC #cmd1`

`scrapy crawl spider -a username=Truc -a password=TMTC #cmd2`

and to crawl it in several commands as I have several accounts.

I managed to check the ip with the code following at the end of the `spider.py`:

```
    yield scrapy.Request('http://checkip.dyndns.org/',meta={'item':item_cheval}, callback=self.checkip)

def checkip(self, response):
    print('IP: {}'.format(response.xpath('//body/text()').re('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')[0]))
```

it returns the same IP in the both commands launched. So my proxy do not manage to give a different IP to each spider.

Someone told me about `bindadress` but I have no idea how it works and if it really gives what I expect.

Notes: I use this in my `middlewares.py`:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = settings.get('HTTP_PROXY')
```

and this in my `settings.py`:

```
# proxy for polipo
HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
....
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'folder.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'folder.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410, #Here for proxy
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None}
```

These are copied patterns I put in my code and it works, but I do not master this skill.

Scrapy version: 1.5.0, Python version: 2.7.9,  Tor version: 0.3.4.8, Vidalia: 0.2.21

Answer (score 0):

If you get a proxy list then you can use 'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy' in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES to chose a random proxy from the list for every new page.

In the settings of your spider:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

PROXY_LIST = 'path/proxylist.txt'
PROXY_MODE = 0
```

With this method there is nothing to add to the spider script

Comment: Excuse me to answer so late, I do bunch of things in the same time. I searched if it was possible to make a proxy list with polipo but I do not find anything about it. So I just searched proxy list, and I found: https://www.proxy-list.download/HTTPS. Do you mean I just have to download the text with a bunch of IP addresses and it is alright?