# How can I check the IP of each spider launched in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, ip

Related to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635927/how-to-set-different-rotating-ip-according-to-different-login-accounts-on-one-si) I would like to know when I launch spiders like this:

`scrapy crawl spider -a username=Bidule -a password=TMTC #cmd1`

`scrapy crawl spider -a username=Truc -a password=TMTC #cmd2`

How to get the current IP for each one?

Notes: in another forum a membre told me the proxy would manage it, but I would like to check if it is true, in order to know if I must change something in my code.

Comment: perhaps this might help ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364630/get-proxy-ip-address-scrapy-using-to-crawl/27373901 or this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366453/8272698

Comment: It finally helped. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get proxy ip address scrapy using to crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364630/get-proxy-ip-address-scrapy-using-to-crawl)

Comment: As far as I know to get the proxy does not give the IP used. All topic's examples done show a `Request` to a website that only returns an IP. Besides even if I use a proxy, when I launch the spiders in the meantime as shown above they both use the same IP actually. That is what I fear and I was able to check it was the case I fear.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a request to a site that returns your IP address, and parse the IP out of the response.

For example, https://httpbin.org/ip

Comment: I did write https://websiteawanttoscrap.com/ip, it returns "this page doesn't exist" in my browser, while your example works in browser. So I need another solution.

Comment: Because I thought to put '/ip' would return the IP as if it was a convention. And I finally used solutions proposed by Julian Silvestri.